# .delete() not working on a record called from signals.py Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a Billing Panel. In the part where a duplicate Billing Address assigned to Order instance, it gets automatically deleted and the previous Billing Address gets assigned to the Order. While the previous Billing Instance gets Assigned to the Order but the duplicate Billing Address Instance is not getting deleted. I am a noob. There is not overridden delete method in the models.

models.py :-

```
class BillingAddress(models.Model):
      #Contains address and email and other info

class Order(models.Model):
      billingAddress = billingAddress = models.ForeignKey(BillingAddress, 
                                     null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL
                                    )
```

signals.py :-

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def dont_save_if_all_fields_matching(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        currentOrder = instance
        previousBilling = BillingAddress.objects.filter(user=currentOrder.user,
                                                        firstname=currentOrder.billingAddress.firstname,
                                                        lastname=currentOrder.billingAddress.lastname,
                                                        phonenumber=currentOrder.billingAddress.phonenumber,
                                                        address1=currentOrder.billingAddress.address1,
                                                        address2=currentOrder.billingAddress.address2,
                                                        city=currentOrder.billingAddress.city,
                                                        country=currentOrder.billingAddress.country,
                                                        state=currentOrder.billingAddress.state,
                                                        pincode=currentOrder.billingAddress.pincode
                                                        )
        if len(previousBilling) > 0:
            currentBillingId = currentOrder.billingAddress.id
            currentOrder.billingAddress = previousBilling[0]
            currentOrder.save()
            BillingAddress.objects.get(id=currentBillingId).delete()
            #The above code is not working
```

Answer (score 0):

previousBilling = BillingAddress.objects.get(id=currentBillingId)
previousBilling.delete()